# Group by 2 Fields as 1 Field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

What I'm trying to do is group users by their **primary** and **secondary** roles and count the amount of users with said roles. The list of users looks like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        roles: {
            primary: 'Cook',
            secondary: null
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        roles: {
            primary: 'Waiter',
            secondary: 'Cashier'
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        roles: {
            primary: 'Cashier',
            secondary: 'Bar Tender'
        }
    }
]
```

And the result should be something like so:

```
[
    {
        role: 'Cook',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        role: 'Waiter',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        role: 'Cashier',
        count: 2
    }
]
```

I'm not quite sure if this is even possible to do, at least in a single `$group` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both field values into an array, [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.collection('crap').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
      "roles": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": ["$roles.primary","$roles.secondary"],
          "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this", null ] }
        }
      }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$roles" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$roles",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }}
])
```

We use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to remove any `null` values in the projected array.

On the documents in the question this would give you:

```
{
    "_id" : "Bar Tender",
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Waiter",
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Cashier",
    "count" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Cook",
    "count" : 1.0
}
```